# okHTTP POST request body with many childs

Tags: java, json, okhttp

I am using a charging API from a carrier, and the following JSON format has to be passed with the API call. I am using okHTTP library.

````
String telNum = "+941234567";

String pbody = "{\"amountTransaction\": {\"clientCorrelator\": \"7659\",\"endUserId\": \"tel:"+telNum+"\",\"paymentAmount\": {\"chargingInformation\": {\"amount\": 1,\"currency\": \"LKR\",\"description\": \"Test Charge\"},\"chargingMetaData\": {\"onBehalfOf\": \"IdeaBiz Test\",\"purchaseCategoryCode\": \"Service\",\"channel\": \"WAP\",\"taxAmount\": \"0\",\"serviceID\": \"theserviceid\"}},\"referenceCode\": \"REF-12345\",\"transactionOperationStatus\": \"Charged\"}}";```
````

The following is how the JSON needs to be formatted.

```
{
    "amountTransaction": {
        "clientCorrelator": "54321",
        "endUserId": "tel:+94761234567",
        "paymentAmount": {
            "chargingInformation": {
                "amount": 1,
                "currency": "LKR",
                "description": "Test Charge"
            },
            "chargingMetaData": {
                "onBehalfOf": "IdeaBiz Test",
                "purchaseCategoryCode": "Service",
                "channel": "WAP",
                "taxAmount": "0",
                "serviceID": "null"
            }  
        },
        "referenceCode": "REF-12345",
        "transactionOperationStatus": "Charged"
    }
}
```

I get Error 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will format your  body according to your need

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(pbody);
        pbody=jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OkHTTP requires `RequestBody` object for `POST`, so try this:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, pbody);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
```